# Catch exception in Play 2 Test + Futures

Tags: scala, testing, playframework

how do I catch an exception inside a future success using play to test?

Here is my code:

```
"A Validity" should {
    "be created based on Client's Mobile" in new WithApplication {
      val objectId = UUIDs.timeBased()
      CValidityServiceModule.checkValidity(true, "MOBILE", clientId, objectId)
      val future = genericService.findByObjectIdAndByClientId(objectId, clientId)

      future.onComplete {
        case Success(s) => {
          s match {
            case Some(v) => {
              v.clientId mustEqual clientId
              v.objectId mustEqual objectId
            }
            case None => assert(false)
          }
        }
        case Failure(t) => {
          assert(false, t.getMessage)
        }
      }
    }
```

Basically if any matcher fail, it trows me an exception, but the test is green.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the `Future` to complete before testing it. Using the `onComplete` callback won't work because the test completes before the `Future`, and the exception is thrown in a different context.

`Await.result` should do it for you:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
val future = genericService.findByObjectIdAndByClientId(objectId, clientId)
val s = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
s match {
  case Some(v) => {
    v.clientId mustEqual clientId
    v.objectId mustEqual objectId
  }
  case None => assert(false)
}
```